# How to show that $\mathbb{E}C_{i+1} = 1 + \mathbb{E}C_i$?

Tags: probability

Consider indicator random variables $Z_i$ and discrete random variables $C_i$ for $i \in \{1,\dots, 100\}$.

Let $\Pr(Z_i = 1) = 1/C_i$ and let $C_{i+1} = (1+Z_i)C_i$.

How can we show that

$$
\mathbb{E}C_{i+1} = 1 + \mathbb{E}C_i \;?
$$

Comment: They aren't, by definition.

Comment: Actually, I do not understand what $P[Z_i=1] = {1 \over C_i}$ means. Surely $P[Z_i=1]$ is a constant depending on $i$ only?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how $P[Z_i = 1]$ can be a random variable?

Comment: @copper.hat $Z_i$ is the random variable which can either be $1$ or $0$. The OP tells us the probability of it being $1$.

Comment: @donald I understand that $Z_i, C_i$ are random variables, that is not what I am asking. The probability of an event (such as $Z_i = 1$) is a number, whereas above you have the probability itself is another random variable ${1 \over C_i}$. So, unless $C_i$ is a constant, I do not understand what the above means? Is there another measure involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use additivity:

$$\mathbb{E}C_{i+1}=\mathbb{E}(1+Z_i) C_i = \mathbb{E}C_i + \mathbb{E} Z_iC_i$$

Now, $\mathbb{E}Z_iC_i=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}[Z_iC_i\mid C_i]\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(C_i\mathbb{E}[Z_i\mid C_i]\right)$. Since $\Pr(Z_i=1)=\tfrac{1}{C_i}$, $\mathbb{E}(Z_i\mid C_i)=\tfrac{1}{C_i}$ which implies $\mathbb{E}(Z_iC_i)=1$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you expland the first two equalities in the line that starts "Now" please. I am not sure where they came from.

Comment: First $=$: This is the law of total expectation: $E(X)=E(E(X\vert Y))$. Second $=$: given $C_i$, the $C_i$ in the inner expectation (left of the $\vert$) is fixed so it can go out of this $\mathbb{E}$.

Comment: Thank you. That is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is already established that:
$$\mathbb{E}C_{i+1}=\mathbb{E}(1+Z_i) C_i = \mathbb{E}C_i + \mathbb{E} Z_iC_i$$.

Note that by LOTUS:

$$\mathbb{E} (Z_iC_i) = \sum Z_iC_i P(Z_iC_i)$$
$$= \sum Z_iC_i P(Z_i|C_i)P(C_i)$$

We only need to consider terms with $Z_i=1$:

$$\mathbb{E} (Z_iC_i) = \sum Z_iC_i P(C_i|Z_i)P(Z_i)$$
$$=\sum C_i P(Z_i=1|C_i)P(C_i)$$
$$=\sum C_i (1/C_i)P(C_i) = \sum P(C_i) = 1$$ .

Comment: Could you explain what LOTUS is?

Comment: LOTUS (Law of Unconscious Statistician) just means we don't need to know that exact probability distribution of the variable which we want the expected value.

Comment: I don't need P(XY) but just P(X,Y).

Comment: Why is this true? $\sum Z_iC_i P(Z_iC_i) = \sum Z_iC_i P(Z_i|C_i)P(C_i)$

Comment: In general $P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$. We don't know $P(AB)$ but we can do something with  $P(A=a,B=b) := P((A=a) \cap (B=b))$

Comment: In other words, I tranformed $P((Z_i=z)*(C_i=c))$  to $P(Z_i=z,C_i=c)$  by LOTUS.